# Catching JavaScript Errors on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webdriver

I've been looking around the web and i couldn't find a solution on how to catch javaScript errors. What I want to do is the when each test runs, i want it to check that each page it access doesn't have a JS error, and if it has i want to save it to a log.

Thanks.
PS all I found is for firefox.

Comment: What did you find...Show the code that is not working for chrome!

Comment: What i found was the following, JSErrorCollector.jar it only works on firefox, here is an example I found on the internet and tried to implement it on my tests. http://selenium.polteq.com/en/capture-javascript-errors-with-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: So this is Selenium ...

Comment: for firefox, use system property `-Dwebdriver.log.file=/tmp/firefox-js-console.log` for selenium standalone server.